# Approach to develop a carousel/slider in Sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I need to develop a carousel/slider on a sharepoin site. This carousel/slider would showcase me different lists in a different format.

I am now stuck up in deciding which architecture to use.

I have the following approaches:

1) Server Object Model
   a) Create different web parts
      and use JQuery and register those user controls in jQuery carousel
2) Client Object Model
   a) Use JQuery and sharepoint web services to project different list items
   b) Use Silverlight

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: D - All of the above.

Any of these options can be used to accomplish the goal. Select the one that best fits the talents and constraints of you, your organization, and your SharePoint server environment and configuration in order to balance development time, maintainability, performance, usability, and reusability.